# Get Details of a Method in C#

Tags: c#, reflection

In C# we can get all the details of a method using the following code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

Type t = doc.GetType();

System.Reflection.MethodInfo[] methods = t.GetMethods();
```

Here I am not able to get the comments of a method and the exceptions available in the method.

Comment: You could use `Type t = typeof(XmlDocument);` and avoid creating an instance.

Comment: The XML documentation is not compiled into the type metadata, if that's what you're trying to get.

Comment: Comments are not available by reflection, they would not be stored in the assembly itself, only in the .pdb file...

Answer (score 4):

Comments are stripped at compile time and not part of the runtime metadata.

As for exceptions, any exception can be thrown from any method. Whereas exceptions in a sense are part of the interface of a method, they are not declared and are therefore not part of the runtime metadata either.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any other way to know the purpose of a method

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by the exceptions available? Unlike Java, in .Net a method does not declare the exceptions that it can throw.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get a list of Exceptions that the method can throw, and comments are removed by the compiler.

Comment: Is there any other way to know the purpose of the method

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to get the comments that are declared on a method like this, because they are not part of the assembly. You can't get the exceptions either, because in C# methods don't declare which exceptions the can throw.